# jenkins: matrix using when, excludes and parameters (Controlling cell behavior at runtime)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm struggling to run the following Jenkins pipeline.
I added a UI parameter (TARGET_FILTER).

The idea is:

- if I select tst, it excludes qua, prd; it executes only 1 value (tst1)
- if I select qua, it excludes tst, prd; it executes 2 values (qua1, qua2)
- if I select prd, it excludes tst, qua; it executes 2 values (prd1, prd2)

I can't make it work, the entire matrix is executed and my excludes are ignored.

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'TARGET_FILTER', choices: ['tst', 'qua', 'prd'], description: 'Run on specific target')
    }
    
    agent any  
    
    stages {
        stage('go') {
            matrix {
                when { anyOf {
                    expression { params.TARGET_FILTER == 'tst' }
                } }
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'TARGET'
                        values 'tst', 'qua', 'prd'
                    }
                    axis {
                        name 'REMOTE'
         

           values 'tst1', 'qua1', 'qua2', 'prd1', 'prd2'
                }
            }
            excludes {
                exclude {
                    axis {
                        name 'TARGET'
                        values 'tst'
                    }
                    axis {
                        name 'REMOTE'
                        values 'qua1', 'qua2', 'prd1', 'prd2'
                    }
                }
                exclude {
                    axis {
                        name 'TARGET'
                        values 'qua'
                    }
                    axis {
                        name 'REMOTE'
                        values 'tst1', 'prd1', 'prd2'
                    }
                }
                exclude {
                    axis {
                        name 'TARGET'
                        values 'prd'
                    }
                    axis {
                        name 'REMOTE'
                        values 'tst1', 'qua1', 'qua2'
                    }
                }
            }
            stages {
                stage('Build') {
                    steps {
                        echo "${params.TARGET}"
                        echo "Do Build for ${TARGET} - ${REMOTE}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}